# killing fragment observing live-data instance in a shared view model

Tags: viewmodel, android-livedata, android-architecture-navigation

I am using shared view model to get values from socket across an activity, with help of observing a live-data instance, and navigation component to navigate between fragments so there's a situation where i show a payment receipt value then user clicks pay this fragment should navigate to another fragment and destroy the first one but what's actually happening it's still alive due to shared view model live-data instance that i was observing, so how to kill this fragment instance when navigating to another fragment

so first i was in trip status -> payment -> thanks

here's my navigation code

```
 private fun updateTripStatusUI(isPayed: Boolean = false) {
        if (isPayed) {
           findNavController(R.id.navigationFragment).popBackStack()
           findNavController(R.id.navigationFragment).navigate(
                    TripStatusFragmentDirections.actionTripStatusFragmentToThanksFragment()
                )
        } else
            findNavController(R.id.navigationFragment).navigate(TripStatusFragmentDirections.actionGlobalPaymentFragment())
    }
```

and here's my graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/trip_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/tripStatusFragment">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/tripStatusFragment"
        android:name="package.TripStatusFragment"
        android:label="fragment_trip_status"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_trip_status">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_tripStatusFragment_to_thanksFragment"
            app:destination="@id/thanksFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/popup_enter"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/popup_exit" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/paymentFragment"
        android:name="package.PaymentFragment"
        android:label="PaymentFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_payment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/thanksFragment"
        android:name="package.ThanksFragment"
        android:label="ThanksFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_thanks" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_paymentFragment"
        app:destination="@id/paymentFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
</navigation>
```

and in ThanksFragment i navigate back to TripStatusFragment with this line

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.tripStatusFragment)
```

Comment: action_tripStatusFragment_to_thanksFragment should be popUpTo="somedestination" and popUpToInclusive="true"

Comment: I updated how i navigate from ThanksFragment to TripStatusFragment again